# I need help understanding a TypeError in a React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make a Kanban clone. I have the following block of code which is giving a TypeError

```
59 |  moveItemLeft(index1,index2) {
58 |     console.log(index1,index2)
60 |     let newArr = this.state.boards.slice();
61 |     let arrItem = newArr[index1].list[index2];
62 |     newArr[index1].list.splice(index2, 1);
63 |     newArr[(index1-1)].list.push(arrItem);
64 |     this.setState({
65 |           boards: newArr,
66 |   })

    }
```

The error I keep getting is

```
TypeError: newArr[(index1 - 1)] is undefined
moveItemLeft
C:/Users/claude/documents/codecademy/premium/reactjs/triplebyte-trello/src/BoardContainer/BoardContainer.js:61
```

on line 61. I can't figure out why I am getting that error, the code should work.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What is the code causing that error? See this Help Center article - [mcve]

Comment: If I try to move an item right on the Kanban I get the listed error which is going back to that one function.

Comment: @Josepch can you verify what's on line 61? The error says a `-1`, but your code snippet says `+1`. If it's `-1`, then are you ever passing in 0 for `index1`?

Comment: accidentally copied in the wrong function, just corrected it.

Comment: Is `index1` a number?

Comment: try to put `console.log(newArr)` after `newArr[index1].list.splice(index2, 1);` see what you get. and check if `index1-1` is a valid index.

Comment: Sorry for being kind of slow getting back to this, I am just going to post a link to my code in github so it doesn't take up a lot of space here, last time I posted more than a method someone got mad and said something about I don't need to post the whole thing and every spec (which I didn't): https://github.com/claudewill1/Projects-and-Coding-Challenges/tree/master/Premium/ReactJS/kanban-clonev.  The function causing the issue is found under src/BoardContainer/BoardContainer.js

Comment: When I run the app, if I press the right arrow in say board two, it moves the item left to board one, the same thing happens from board 3 back to board 1. Anytime I try to move an item right after they all get moved to the first board from pressing the right arrow, I get the error which leads me to the above function.

Comment: @Take-Some-Bytes yes it is a number. I apologize for taking so long to get back to you.

Comment: I seems to only be throwing that error when it is in the first board, I can figure out why stuff only moves left/up later, but I think I could create a conditional statement that checks if  index == 0 ? break : "function goes here"

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting clear scenario in your question without further lines of code. However, what I am understanding here is that the arrays are empty when line 61 is getting interpreted and it is getting value afterwards. please try placing line 61 after 63.

Comment: I posted a link to the directory in my github above, last time I posted the amount of could that would be needed some "moderators" came in and told me that I shouldn't post that much code for whatever their reasoning, and they should know  that I am a new user to stackoverflow.

Comment: I cant figure out how to post code correctly in comments. I tried " ``` ":
render() {
        return (
        <div className="board-wrapper">
            {
                this.state.boards.map((item,i) => {
                    return <Board name={item.name} color={item.color} items={item.items} addItem={this.addItem.bind(this,i)} moveItemLeft={this.moveItemLeft.bind(this,i)} moveItemRight={this.moveItemRight.bind(this,i)} key={i} boardIndex={i} boardLength={this.state.boards.length}/>
                })
            }
            
        </div>
        )
    }

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem on line 63 I did the following:

```
if(index1 !== 0) newArr[(index1-1)].list.push(arrItem);
```

for whatever reason, the right arrow calls the moved left method which I will figure out. So if index1 == 0, it cannot be decreased any farther. The same change will be made to the moveRight function, however, it will be if(index1 !== index1.length - 1).

Thank you everyone for your help.